# Ctrl+C does not work in gnome-terminal

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, signals, gnome-terminal

On my Linux host, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not seem to work and I do not know how to proceed to make it work. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 with bash 4.1.5(1), and working in Gnome-terminal.

When I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while this script was running, it did not cause it to quit.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 500`
do
        ps -e > /dev/null
        echo $i
done
```

Comment: What do you mean by “does not work”? Where did you press that key, what did you expect to happen, what actually happened?

Comment: Maybe you can describe further details of why you think that Ctrl-C does not work -- there are certain kernel level things which is not interruptible -- for example a process hanging waiting for a (failed) NFS answer can frequently not be interrupted

Comment: I updated my answer. Basically Ctrl C did not terminate a script, that I think should be terminated on doing Ctrl C.

Comment: Does `stty -a` output contain `intr=^C`? How do you run the script?

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions. Choose the site you want to ask on, and tailor it to that site.

Comment: You're right that the script should be terminated if you press `Ctrl+C`. In what terminal did you do this? Does it happen in another terminal? What happens if you run `sleep 5` and then press `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: Its regular terminal in Ubuntu. It is /dev/pts/0 if that helps. It happens in any terminal on my computer. If I do sleep 5 and do Ctrl C nothing happens. Nothing is printed to the console also.

Comment: I run the script by doing ./hello.sh

Comment: @abc: have you tried to use a different terminal emulator (xterm, rxvt, …)?

Comment: when I tried using xterm I was able to Ctrl C sleep 10. But with gnome-terminal Ctrl C on sleep 10 did not work. Why is that ?

Comment: So using gnome-terminal Ctrl C works but Ctrl c does not. So to interrupt sleep 10 if I do Ctrl + Shift + c it works. But doing Ctrl + c does not work. Why is it case sensitive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to do this

```
$ stty sane
```

and see if it fixes the problem, also check if the intr is set correctly using

```
$ stty -a
```

If you find that `intr` is set to something different than ^C, then you can also fix it by typing

```
$ stty intr ^v^c
```

Comment: This did not help. stty -a shows "intr = ^C" ( without the quotes)

Comment: Do I have to type the ^ character or press the Ctrl key?

Comment: you just have to press the Ctrl key (^ is short for Ctrl-)

Comment: Maybe you can describe further details of why you think that Ctrl-C does not work -- there are certain kernel level things which is not interruptible -- for example a process hanging waiting for a (failed) NFS answer can frequently not be interrupted

Comment: I added more details to my question. Basically Ctrl C is not terminating a script that I am running, which I expect to be terminated on Ctrl C.

Comment: So using gnome-terminal Ctrl C works but Ctrl c does not. So to interrupt sleep 10 if I do Ctrl + Shift + c it works. But doing Ctrl + c does not work. Why is it case sensitive.

Answer (score 10):

The default settings in `gnome-terminal` binds the `Ctrl-C` and `Ctrl-V` keys to emulate the copy-and-paste behaviour of Windows. It was meant to be a feature not a bug :)

To disable this, at the gnome-terminal,

1. navigate to `Menubar -> Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts`
2. click on the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the Shortcut Key column until you see `New Accelerator...`.
3. press the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to disable the key binding
4. verify that `Disabled` now appear in the Shortcut Key column.

Note that this change will be *immediately effective* on *all* gnome-terminals.

*Tip: `gnome-terminal --show-menubar` will force gnome-terminal to show the Menubar if it is not shown.*

Comment: You saved my day! Had a `Strg+C` inside "Terminal / reset" keyboard shortcuts... and canceling a command didn't work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

Since it looks like a broken `gnome-terminal` configuration, you can try letting it restore the defaults using

```
mv .gconf/apps/gnome-terminal{,-BROKEN}
```

(You'll need to re-start the terminal to see the effects.)

If everything is fine after that, do a `rm -rf .gconf/apps/gnome-terminal-BROKEN`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a guess here: Ctrl-C does work, but because `ps -e` takes a long time to run relative to the rest of the script, that all you do is send SIGINT to the "ps" process.  "ps" exits, and the script picks right up with another iteration through the loop code.

Do a `sleep 10` in your bash window, while it runs, control-C it.  See if that works.  If it does, run your original script, and control-C it multiple times.  Sooner or later, you'll get lucky and the bash process that interprets the script will get the SIGINT.

Comment: Ctrl C on sleep 10 does not work either.

Comment: So using gnome-terminal Ctrl C works but Ctrl c does not. So to interrupt sleep 10 if I do Ctrl + Shift + c it works. But doing Ctrl + c does not work. Why is it case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that you don't have `CTRL+C` already mapped as a `Copy to Clipboard` shortcut. If so, this will override the `CTRL+C to quit` that you're used to.

Linux terminals often come with `SHIFT+CTRL+C` as the default `Copy to Clipboard` shortcut and many users (including me) change this to `CTRL+C` as that's more intuitive coming from another OS.

Consider mapping the stop process shortcut to `CTRL+X` so you don't have to change your `Copy to Clipboard` muscle memory:

```
stty intr ^x
```

Comment: not sure why this answer was minused, its really good :)

Answer (score 1):

When I looked at my shortcuts for terminal I see that the shortcut for "copy" is set to <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. So I changed it to <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (for copying).

Now everything is working.

Be sure to check

```
stty -a
```

and make sure intr is set to `^C` before checking the shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old topic, but stupid mistakes have no age! <kbd>;)</kbd>

I recently had changed <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd>-<kbd>**C**</kbd> to a shortcut for copying text and forgot about it.

After changing the shortcut for copy to <kbd>**SHIFT**</kbd>-<kbd>**INS**</kbd> now <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd>-<kbd>**C**</kbd> is working again in the terminal!