# Interrupt sequence CTRL+C does not work for user

Tags: kill, gnome-terminal, interrupt

In any terminal operating under GNOME, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I only see a question mark. Same goes for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. The output of `stty -a | grep intr` is:

```
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
```

I can use the sequence under all other tty's (outside X), and can also use it for another user; only one user is affected. How can I fix this?

Comment: What shell does that user use? Could you post the contents of the profile file (typically `.bashrc` for bash)?

Comment: shell: bash, os: gentoo. The profile is located in /etc/profile. I put its output in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HSDNzJTX). But I don't think something is wrong in it. Its the same for all users.

Comment: `/etc/profile` is the global file - I meant the **user** profile, which in that case should be `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`.

Comment: [.bashrc and .bash_profile](http://pastebin.com/jQCTQJjm) They are the same as the other users also.

Comment: If you try a different terminal such as `xterm`, does `Ctrl+C` work there? What is displayed if you enter `echo '^V^C' | hd`, where you must type `Ctrl+V` then `Ctrl+C` where I wrote `^V^C`?

Comment: @Gilles What is `hd` supposed to do? It is not present on my system.

Comment: This question looks similar [to this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18589/ctrlc-does-not-work-in-gnome-terminal/) - but I'm not sure if it can be called a duplicate. Omar, could you please verify this?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz `hd` is the same as `hexdump -C`, which is like `od -t x1 -A x` but with an extra column showing printable characters, plus it's more memorable. It's a BSD utility, which Debian and Ubuntu ship; other Linux distributions may ship only `hexdump` or neither.

Comment: @Gilles Ctrl+C works under xterm, as well as the tty's. It does not work under gnome-terminal, lxterminal. The output from echo `echo '^V^C' | hexdump` on **xterm** is `0000000 0316 000a // 0000003` where **//** is newline. On **gnome-terminal**, The output from `echo '??' | hexdump` is `0000000 3f3f 000a // 0000003`. Please note that the sequences CTRL+Z, CTRL+C, CTRL+V show a ? on the terminal each time it is pressed.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz I have been to this [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18589/ctrlc-does-not-work-in-gnome-terminal) before and have tried their recommendations. They don't work for me. Besides, their problem is about not being able to stop a particular script. In my case, everything that can run in a terminal is affected.

Comment: Omar - It is strange, since your answer (below) indicates a problem with `gnome-terminal` configuration. Did [my answer to that other question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18589/ctrlc-does-not-work-in-gnome-terminal/18624#18624) not solve anything?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz yes I did try your solution earlier on. But instead of using mv, I straight away rm'ed the folder.  However, since the problem was not only limited to gnome-terminal (LXDE's LxTerminal was also affected), I deduced it must be something other than .gconf's terminal settings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lied somewhere in the keyboard preferences under *gnome-keyboard-properties*. `Reset to defaults` under layout fixed everything. I was able to then re-do the same settings I had before. The good thing is, it works now. The bad thing, I could not catch the specific reason why it behaved this way.