# Ctrl+z, Ctrl+x, Ctrl+c are not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard

My keyboard is messing up. I can click on <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> fine and I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save file, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate line (in Atom) without any problem. All keys works fine.

But the strange thing is that I cannot use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut. It does not show any warning or error.

It does that in all IDEs, Browsers and text editors.

Even when I run `top` command in terminal I cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop it.

I tried to follow [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18589/ctrlc-does-not-work-in-gnome-terminal#) but I got lost.

**What can I do?**

Comment: Can you edit to say if this is a laptop keyboard - and if so, what is the brand and model of the laptop - or if it is an external keyboard?

Comment: The command `stty sane` in the linked answer only helps inside a terminal, it will not affect the browser.  So the problem it fixes is not the problem you have (or at least not the *only* problem :-).

Comment: It is probably quite difficult to work out your problem :-).  What keyboard layout do you use - is it an American or British QWERTY layout, or something different?  Are you able to try booting a Live media, what version is it and does it have the same problem?  If you are dual-booting, do you have the same problem in Windows or not?

Comment: At a guess I'd hazard that your keyboard definition doesn't match the actual keyboard you're using.

Comment: Did it used to work and now it stopped working, or has it never worked correctly on this install of Ubuntu?

Comment: @sourcejedi

yes it was working before, and yes it's a laptop.  
language English (US).

**I don't remember doing anything to the keyboard layout.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my keybord is dead!.

just installed windows as dual boot and it's doing the same.

so let me just close the **Q**